# Yup: Validate String Array with Single Element which must be 'Y'

Tags: formik, yup

I need to validate the following structure:

```
"cert1" : [
   "Y"
]
```

It's a single "Acknowledge Term/Condition" checkbox. This must be provided at all times (required). But the following Yup expressions don't work:

```
cert1: yup.array().of(yup.string().matches(/^Y$/, "The selection must be Yes"))

cert1: yup.array().of(yup.string().matches(/^Y$/, "The selection must be Yes").required('Required'))
```

When the checkbox is not selected, I'm able to submit the form without it.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is below, but I don't like it. First of all, I don't have a `mixed` type, I have a clearly defined string array. Second, I wish I could replace `length & includes` with "exactly 1 element matches..."

```
yup.mixed().test('test-cert1', 'Answer must be selected', (value, context) => {
      return Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 1 && value.includes('Y')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a checkbox why not just use boolean:

```
terms: Yup.bool().oneOf([true], requiredText)
```